# Ansible handling password change on first login

Tags: ansible, change-password

I am creating a playbook that login to a Virtual Machine and perform initial configuration. The image used to create the VM has a default user name that need change of password on initial login. I am looking for a way how to handle this in Ansible?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for my problem as follow using ansible module "expect" https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html

```
- name: Change password on initial login
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  become: no
  expect:
    command: ssh {{ ansible_ssh_common_args }} {{ user_expert }}@{{ inventory_hostname }}
    timeout: 20
    responses:
      Password: "{{ user_expert_password }}"
      UNIX password: "{{ user_expert_password }}"
      New password: "{{ user_expert_password_new }}"
      new password:  "{{ user_expert_password_new }}"
      "\\~\\]\\$": exit
  register: status
```

Comment: If you try to run a playbook against an inventory list that includes servers that need their password changed on first log in you will get an error like "Password change required but no TTY available".
This is because ansible is trying to ssh to the host before your task even starts running and gets that error. You will need to loop on a list of IP addresses in your task while running your ansible playbook only against localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) module, especially the [password](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#parameter-password) option.

Keep in mind, that the `password` option needs the hash of the actual password. Check [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-encrypted-passwords-for-the-user-module) how to get that it. (It needs to be hashed, otherwise you would have a cleartext password in your playbook or inventory which would be a security risk.)

Example:

```yaml
- name: ensure password of default user is changed
  user:
    name: yourdefaultuser
    password: '$6$QkjC8ur2WfMfYGA$ZNUxTGoe5./F0b4GJGrcEA.ff9An473wmPsmU4xv00nSrN4D/Nxk8aKro/E/LlQVkUJLbLL6qk2/Lxw5Oxs2m.'
```

Note that the password hash was generated with `mkpasswd --method=sha-512` for the password `somerandompassword`.

Comment: Please re-read my question.
When VM is deployed ansible cannot access it since it can not allow you to login with default user name and password until the password is changed.

Comment: Your question says "has a default user name that need change of password on initial login" which is not what your last comment says. Your question does not state, that you can not log in using those credentials. However, how would you log in at all? Why can you not log in with the default credentials?

Comment: To avoid confusion below are the logs when i ssh to the VM first time from my system 

~~~
# ssh default@X.X.X.X 
IF YOU ARE NOT AN AUTHORIZED USER, PLEASE EXIT IMMEDIATELY

Password: 
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Changing password for expert.
(current) UNIX password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
~~~

how to handle this via Ansible ?

Comment: That looks like a custom message, What kind of image is that, who created it?

Comment: Its a telco VNF .. forcing a user to change password on first login is normal in linux . If you create a user with option "-e " the user will be forced to change the password on initial login.