# Become su when using vmware_vm_shell module to configure Linux VM using ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible, vmware

I have a working ansible playbook which uses [vmware_vm_shell module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_vm_shell_module.html) to push network configuration commands to a Linux VM running in VMware. This only works if I use the vm_username as **'root'**. I want to use a different user other than 'root' and become 'su' to run network configuration cli commands. Please refer to the working ansible playbook below:

```
  - name: Edit Network Interfaces for VM
    vmware_vm_shell:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: "{{ vcenter_validate_certs }}"
        datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
        folder: "{{ vcenter_destination_folder }}"
        vm_id: VM-Test
        vm_username: root
        vm_password: "{{ vm-password }}"
        vm_shell: "/bin/nmcli"
        vm_shell_args: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
    - "con mod ens192 ipv4.address '{{ vmintip }}'"
    - "con mod ens192 ipv4.gateway '{{ intup }}'"
    - "con mod ens192 ipv4.dns '{{ dnsip }}'"
    - "con mod ens192 ipv4.method manual"
    - "con mod ens192 ipv6.method disabled"
    - "con up ens192"
    - "con mod 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.address '{{ vmmgip}}'"
    - "con mod 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.gateway '{{ mgup }}'"
    - "con mod 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.dns '{{ dnsip }}'"
    - "con mod 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.method manual"
    - "con mod 'Wired connection 1' ipv6.method disabled"
    - "con up 'Wired connection 1'"
```

I was unsuccessful when using a different username, it was unable to issue those commands since I need to have root privilege (I need to become su using that different username). Is there a way to become su when using a different user with vmware_vm_shell module?

Comment: Does the `user` you want to use for this already exist inside the VM, is he part of a `group` allowed to run `sudo`?

Comment: @tink Thank you for your prompt reply! The user does exist in the VM, I was able to execute 'sudo -l -U user' command to verify that he is allowed to run sudo. Please correct me if I am wrong, to run nmcli commands the user needs to be in su. When I run the command as a user, it fails since the user is not becoming su and running the nmcli command as a normal user.

Comment: That is correct. If he is allowed to execute those sudo commands w/o an extra password you should be able to replace `vm_shell: "/bin/nmcli"` with `vm_shell: "/path/to/sudo"` (for me it's `/usr/bin/sudo` and add network mangler to the arguments `vm_shell_args: "/bin/nmcli {{ item }}"` ...

Comment: @tink That is smart, thank you! I have adjusted the playbook to your recommendation and it returns with "Failed to authenticate with the guest operating system using the supplied credentials". I noticed this hardened RHEL image prompts to change password for initial login. I consoled into the VM changed the password with initial login, ran the playbook again with the new password, and it works! The new playbook should follow this order: Step#1 Change the initial password for the VM, Step#2 Run the sudo nmcli task.

Comment: @tink Similar to sudo and nmcli, is there a vm_shell path that I can use to change the password? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I'm sure it could be done, but given the fact you're being prompted on login it would require `expect` or somesuch, and I really don't want to go there ;)

Comment: Maybe start a new question for the `expect` part?

Comment: @tink Sounds good will do that, thanks again!

Comment: maybe you don't need to: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64711268/1394729) help?

Comment: @tink That does provide some insight. Since these VMs has no IP configured initially, I will not be able to SSH into it. I will adjust the user in the VM golden template to not have a password expiry, so it will not prompt for change password during initial login. Maybe not best security practice but it will work for now :)

Comment: That would work, too. You could also use the `expect` executable that's installed by default on most linux distros, rather than the module, and use the same method you applied to `sudo` & `nmcli` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the comment into an answer:

If the user is allowed to execute those sudo commands w/o an extra password, you should be able to replace `vm_shell: "/bin/nmcli"` with `vm_shell: "/path/to/sudo"` (for me it's /usr/bin/sudo and add network mangler to the arguments `vm_shell_args: "/bin/nmcli {{ item }}"`.